# Building Pre-existing .NET Application on Mono with Visual Studio Package Dependencies

Tags: mono, vs-unit-testing-framework

Let me preface this by saying I'm not very familiar with .NET. I'm running a mac machine and installed mono. When I attempt the build the .NET project the below error is received.

Error:CS0234: The type or namespace name `VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace`Microsoft'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Based on my research I suspect this is due to the lack of Visual Studio packages in mono.

Is there a way that the Visual Studio tools specifically Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework can be installed on a mac running mono?

I attempted to install via nuget but the package on nuget doesn't seem to be compatible with the version for the project I'm trying to build.